# Additional Permission While Using Google SignIn button

Tags: google-signin, scopes, google-api-js-client, google-api-javascript-client

I am using Google Sign in Button in my Website. I am able to authorise users and get the user's profile information.

I have followed this [Integrating Google Sign-In into your web app](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in)

```
<div id="my-signin2" ></div>

gapi.signin2.render('my-signin2', {
            'scope': 'profile email',
            'width': 240,
            'height': 50,
            'longtitle': true,
            'theme': 'light',
            'onsuccess': this.onSuccess,
            'onfailure': this.onFailure
        });

      onSuccess(googleUser) {
               var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
                var name = googleUser.getBasicProfile().getName());
                var email = googleUser.getBasicProfile().getEmail());
                var imageUrl = googleUser.getBasicProfile().getImageUrl());

      }
      onFailure(error) {
      }
```

Now i need to read the users contacts while he authorises using google.

So for getting the contacts I have added a scope

**https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly**

```
        gapi.signin2.render('my-signin2', {
            'scope': 'profile email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly',
            'width': 240,
            'height': 50,
            'longtitle': true,
            'theme': 'light',
            'onsuccess': this.onSuccess,
            'onfailure': this.onFailure
        });
```

Every thing is working fine. After User authorize using gmail, It shows permissions screen to the user and asks for the permission.

But When the user denies the permission, it is not even logging the user. I want user to be logged in even if he denies, its ok if i don't get their contacts.

I have read about [requesting additional scopes.](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/incremental-auth)

```
        var options = new gapi.auth2.SigninOptionsBuilder(
                {'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly'});

        googleUser = auth2.currentUser.get();
        googleUser.grant(options).then(
            function(success){
              console.log(JSON.stringify({message: "success", value: success}));
            },
            function(fail){
              alert(JSON.stringify({message: "fail", value: fail}));
            });
```

When I use this after in onSuccess(After user authorises the email), it always goes to fail method. Giving error "**popup_closed_by_user**"

Answer (score 1):

As per the discussion in this [thread](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/293)

Found the solution.

Created another button for requesting additional scope and called grant method onClick of button.

If you set options like this it is not working

```
var options = new gapi.auth2.SigninOptionsBuilder(
            {'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly'});
```

For getting the scopes you should use the methods

```
let googleUser = auth2.currentUser.get();

var options = new gapi.auth2.SigninOptionsBuilder();
options.setScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly');


googleUser.grant(options).then(
        function(success){
          console.log(JSON.stringify({message: "success", value: success}));
        },
        function(fail){
          alert(JSON.stringify({message: "fail", value: fail}));
});
```

Comment: May I know how should I connect this on the step 1 of this link https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/incremental-auth